# Django queryset for DRF view

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

I have model called Category where we can add the categories and the records will be a manytomanyfield to Records Model what can my queries be to display all the categories on one page and the if i click on the particular category i should get only records related to that particular category.

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    records = models.ManytoManyField(Record)

class Record(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

**views.py**

```
class CategoryListView(ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = ?
        return queryset

class RecordListView(ListAPIView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = ?
        return queryset
```

/categories/page/

- Category 1
- Category 2
- Category 3
- Category 4

/Category/Records/page/
Category 1

- record 1
- record 2
- record 3